# Is Erlang's httpd a good solution to host a webapp?

Tags: apache, erlang

I am learning Erlang and found out it contains [httpd](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpd.html) which I managed to configure and make serve to my needs for creating an API service.

I know there are other solutions like mochiweb and Cowboy which must be undoubtedly great choice but I want to begin lean and bare bones.

When I decide to release my project, will it be a good plan to use Erlang's httpd regarding performance and HTTP features like HTTPS, HTTP/2, performance,  or should I choose another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpd is powerful webserver and a perfectly valid choice for production, as long as it fits your needs. I think the main reason to go for other alternative webservers is that you find that some functionality is missing in httpd that you find somewhere else. For example, I don't think httpd supports websockets, however websockets are supported by for instance cowboy and yaws.

> When I decide to release my project, will it be a good plan to use
>   Erlang's httpd regarding performance and HTTP features like HTTPS,
>   HTTP/2, performance, or should I choose another server?

I can't find any benchmarks comparing httpd with the other solutions that you mention, like cowboy and mochiweb, but I've not heard any complaints about the peformance of httpd and I would guess that it's as good as cowboy and mochiweb for production. The fact that it's shipped with the erlang language is a good reason for assuming that the code is performant and battle-tested, if you want to go in depth you can always:

1. look at the source: https://github.com/erlang/otp.
2. Make your own benchmarks.

Comment: I would doubt HTTP/2 as well.